# Is it possible for a Azure Container App to access on-prem network share using a UNC path?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

Hey all I've been trying to look into whether this is possible or not.

I was working with Infra-Engineering to setup a VNet with peering to the on-prem network. Everything was smooth sailing until we found out that the Azure Sandbox for Function Apps blocks the SMB ports. I saw a reply on this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/290531/how-can-i-access-a-on-premise-network-file-share-d.html
that if we use a Container App that we would not have this restriction. Can anyone corroborate this? I just want to get some insight before committing to trying this out.

Comment: azure container for function/webapp shoudl work as well. Azure container App, or Azure kubernetes will work as well.

Comment: That article does **not** say that Container Apps will work. It says to use the app service to run a container.

Comment: Very specifically a Windows container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - you need a VPN/Express Route connection to on premise, the container app needs to be in a VNet peered with the VPN VNet (if separated), a DNS server able to resolve on-premises DNS records, if there are firewalls, NSGs involved you will also need access rules there, and obviously the IP address ranges need to be routed (BGP or Static) and should not overlap

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-container-apps-virtual-network-integration/ba-p/3096932

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/hybrid-dns-infra